# Android: time listener

Tags: android, service, time, listener

Is there a time listener in Android?
I have a service that implements a location Listener. When there is no GPS lock, eg in a subway, I would like to send a notification based on time.

eg. If the train arrives at station A at 12:30.
If the current clock is 12:30, I would like to send a notification to the user.

The problem is that I didn't find anywhere a method for "onTimeChanged". Is there any way to achieve that?
I know about the `System.currentTimeMillis())` but where do I put it to check every second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TimerTask class http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html  which would help you to schedule new Task after some time interval.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to achieve this using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running.

Comment: Yes but can I show a notification based on the alarm manager?

Comment: Yes, of course. Using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Comment: Ok, will try and let you know

Comment: could you please post an example? I do not seem to figure how to do that. I am kind of new to Android

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used this myself. This is a common task though, you should find examples or tutorials on google.